# Entity Framework Core - dynamic filtering

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, filtering

I'm having an issue retrieving correct result from database using Entity Framework Core.

Here is my `Article` table:

[image]

I would like to create dynamic filter using `IQueryable` that will return the following results:

```
Select a.Id, a.Name, a.BrandId, a.GenderId
from dbo.Articles a
where GenderId in (1)
  and BrandId in (1, 2, 3)
```

which returns:

[image]

This is my controller action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Clothes()
{
    var model = new ArticleFilterViewModel();
    model.Genders.AddRange(new int[1] { 1 });
    model.Brands.AddRange(new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 });
    var result = await articleSerivce.GetFilteredUsers(model);
    return View(result);
}
```

Here is my repository method for fetching filtered articles:

```
public ICollection<Article> GetFilteredUsers(ArticleFilter filter)
{
    var articles = GetAll();
    articles = FilteredByBrand(articles, filter.Brands);
    articles = FilteredByGender(articles, filter.Genders);
    var result = articles.ToList();
    return result;
}

IQueryable<Article> FilteredByBrand(IQueryable<Article> articles,  List<int> items)
{
    return articles.WhereIf(items.IsNotNullOrEmpty(),  x => items.Contains(x.BrandId));
}

IQueryable<Article> FilteredByGender(IQueryable<Article> articles, List<int> items)
{
     return articles.WhereIf(items.IsNotNullOrEmpty(), x => items.Contains(x.GenderId));
}
```

After this code is executed I get the following:

[image]

I get 3 articles as a result instead of 2 (Article Id's: 2,3,2).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks ok to me. So you are getting objects with duplicate PK (2,3,2)? Sounds weird.

Comment: Yes. This is what bothers me

Comment: Can you provide a repro project, so we can take a look?

Comment: @Ivan Stoev Where would you like me to send you zip file?

Comment: You can provide a public downloadable link in your question (Dropbox, OneDrive, GitHub etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what your `WhereIf()` method do or what your really get from `GetAll()` but if I replace `WhereIf()` by `Where()` it works as expected.

```
private IQueryable<Article> FilteredByBrand(IQueryable<Article> articles, List<int> items)
{
    return items.IsNullOrEmpty() ? articles : articles.Where(x => items.Contains(x.BrandId));
}

private IQueryable<Article> FilteredByGender(IQueryable<Article> articles, List<int> items)
{
    return items.IsNullOrEmpty() ? articles : articles.Where(x => items.Contains(x.GenderId));
}
```

Returns

> 2 - Cool t-shirt - 2 - 1
>   3 - Yellow panties - 3 - 1

[Here is my complete repro code.](https://gist.github.com/BizyDev/2d764d4abd25f726efe292fed9e52e17)

Comment: Thanks. It seams that problem is in WhereIf function.
'        public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, bool condition, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
        {
            if (condition)
                return source.Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
            else
                return source;
        }
'

Comment: @user3569465 Then apparently it's wrong. I was expecting it to be `public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, bool condition, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate) { return condition ? source.Where(predicate) : source; }`. Note the `Expression<Func<…>>` - never use `Func<..>` with `IQueryable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

With EF Core, try this.

Simple and performatic dynamic filter

```
public static List<Inventory> GetAll(string po, string cod)
{
    using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var Items = context.Inventorys
            .Where(p => p.CodigoPO == po || po == string.Empty)
            .Where(p => p.CodigoProduto == cod || cod == string.Empty).ToList();
        return Items;
    }
}
```

[image: Generated by EF Core, using only the PO parameter]
[image: Generated by EF Core, using only the PO parameter]